# EclipseLink MongoDB connection

Tags: java, mongodb, jpa, eclipselink, persistence.xml

I have MongoDB database called test with collection called USstates. Now I connect to db using Eclipselink

```
EntityManagerFactory emf =  Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("mongo");

        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
```

But find operation always return null. In MongoDB shell to use find I need to type

```
db.USstates.find({...})
```

I don't know where to define in my application that I want to use USstates collection. In persistence.xml I specify connection but not collection:

```
<property name="eclipselink.nosql.property.mongo.port" value="27017"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.nosql.property.mongo.host" value="localhost"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.nosql.property.mongo.db" value="test"/>
```

So... where should I notify my application that I want to use USstates? or it is not necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collection name is specified in class in @NoSql anotation as value of dataType.
Example:

> @Entity
>   @NoSql(dataType="USstates", dataFormat=DataFormatType.MAPPED)
>   public class UsStatesClass {
>   ...
>   }